# Html tags inside json/ld articleBody value?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, json-ld

If I want to create an [Article](https://schema.org/Article) *schema.org type* with a json/ld format, should I have to put the html tags inside the `articleBody`'s value?

Because I saw that if I use microdata, in the [Structured Data Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?hl=it#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tomshw.it%2Fdestiny-si-prepara-all-evento-di-halloween-tutte-le-novita-80881) it appears the `articleBody` as a plain text without html tags.

Thanks

Comment: See also: [Inline Microdata content displays different from same markup in JSON-LD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36306219/1591669)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just plain text:

```
"articleBody": "You can paste your entire post in here, and yes it can get really really long."
```

Sources:

1. http://jsonld.com/article/
2. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles

Comment: I cannot find the text-only requirement in the provided links. Just the example isn't using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

JSON-LD value is plain text, so although it won't be an issue if you still include HTML entities in it, they will simply be interpreted as text. Including the `<` and `>` characters.