# JSON-LD: HTML code examples in the articleBody

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

In the article, I have a couple of examples of an HTML code (text not images). Should I skipped them and include content without the code examples? I'm using `TechArticle` and the article content is placed in `articleBody`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html tags inside json/ld articleBody value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136035/html-tags-inside-json-ld-articlebody-value)

Answer (score 2):

You can include the HTML examples in the `articleBody` property.

In JSON-LD values, the characters `<` and `>` have no special meaning, so the HTML [won’t get interpreted, it’s just plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36359288/1591669).

#### Alternative

If you want to provide metadata about the code examples, or if they are more like attachments instead of inlined, you can use the [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) property (on `Article`) to provide [`SoftwareSourceCode`](http://schema.org/SoftwareSourceCode) items (bold emphasis mine):

> Computer programming source code. Example: Full (compile ready) solutions, **code snippet samples**, scripts, templates.

While HTML is not a programming language, I think it should be fine to use it for HTML, too. The `programmingLanguage` property expects a [`ComputerLanguage`](http://schema.org/ComputerLanguage) value, which says (bold emphasis mine):

> This type covers computer programming languages such as Scheme and Lisp, **as well as other language-like computer representations**.