# Error in Structured Data Testing Tool for JSON-LD published with GTM: "Missing ',' or '}' in object declaration."

Tags: google-tag-manager, json-ld

I am trying to add structured markup to a store page using GTM and JSON-LD. Here is the code:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "SportingGoodsStore",
  "name": "SAIL",
  "image": "https://www.sail.ca/media/stores/z-12-lat_45.451220021743-lon_45.451220021743-510x350.png",
  "@id": "https://www.sail.ca/fr/nos-magasins/brossard",
  "url": "https://www.sail.ca/fr/nos-magasins/brossard",
  "telephone": "450 321-1835",
  "priceRange": "$$",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "8780, boul. Leduc",
    "addressLocality": "Brossard",
    "addressRegion": "QC",
    "postalCode": "J4Y 0G4",
    "addressCountry": "CA"
  },
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": 45.4514453,
    "longitude": -73.44171039999998
  },
  "openingHoursSpecification": [{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": [
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday"
    ],
    "opens": "10:00",
    "closes": "18:00"
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": [
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday"
    ],
    "opens": "10:00",
    "closes": "21:00"
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Saturday",
    "opens": "09:00",
    "closes": "17:00"
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
    "opens": "10:00",
    "closes": "17:00"
  }]
}
</script>
```

This code is inserted on my page using a custom HTML tag in GTM, and it is published on the store page. Using https://jsonlint.com/, I made sure that the JSON-LD seemed to be valid. However, when I scan the URL with Google’s structured data testing tool, I still get the following error message:

> Missing ',' or '}' in object declaration.

Even worse, when I copy paste the code in the structured data testing tool using the "code snippet" test instead of the URL test, there is no error messaging.

Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the URL of a page that gives this error?

Comment: Sure! The link is https://www.sail.ca/fr/nos-magasins/brossard

Answer (score 0):

(The JSON-LD you included in the question is different from the JSON-LD in the linked document. The following is based on the latter.)

Your JSON-LD contains the following:

```json
"description": "<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm;">HTML with &eacute; and <strong>more HTML</strong></p>",
```

The error is that the value contains unescaped `"` characters. Because of this, the JSON-LD will be parsed as

```json
"description": "<p style=",
```

and the rest of the content will make it invalid.

To fix it, you have to escape any `"` in the value as `\"`, e.g.:

```json
"description": "<p style=\"margin-bottom: 0cm;\">HTML with &eacute; and <strong>more HTML</strong></p>",
```

(Note that you would ideally [use plain text instead of HTML in the value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36359288/1591669). Schema.org’s [`description`](https://schema.org/description) property doesn’t expect an HTML value.)

Comment: Hey Unor, thank you for the answer. However, I can attest that the script below is exactly what I've published to this page using Tag Manager. However, I'm wondering if the GTM structured data is properly read by the Structured Data Testing Tool, and by Google in general...   also, thank you for the pointer regarding the escaped ". I don't really have access to edit the code right now, but I'll keep it in mind next time we open the code.

Comment: @JohnMichael: Well, the page you linked has two JSON-LD `script` elements, one with a `LocalBusiness` top-level element, and one with an `Organization` top-level element. There is no JSON-LD with `SportingGoodsStore`.